# Drupal 7 get nid in node view block tpl

Tags: templates, drupal-7, block, nodes

I had to modify a view block tpl (`views-view-[xyz]--block.tpl.php`)

In this block, only one node is displayed (the latest of it's type). I have to get its node id (nid) in this file. How can I proceed?

I don't find anything about it on the Internet.

Thanks

Comment: What about $row->nid?

Comment: To Djouuuuh, Doesn't work. For those who will have the same issue here are some solutions: You can use entity view in your view block instead of the fields. Then in the hook_node_view you will have easy acces to the nid. Or you can use the fields and add the fiels "Nid" and via the views-view-field.tpl.php ou have direct access to the nid. But for my case, i didn't want to use the entity view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who will have the same issue here are some solutions:

You can use entity view in your view block instead of the fields. Then in the hook_node_view you will have easy acces to the nid.

Or you can use the fields and add the fiels "Nid" and via the views-view-field.tpl.php ou have direct access to the nid.